# Is the sentence "horse meat is dog meat" a contradiction?

Tags: ambiguity

> > Other compounds reveal other meaning relations between the parts,
> >     which are not entirely consistent because many compounds are idiomatic
> >     ... a magnifying glass is a glass that magnifies;
> >     but a looking glass is not a glass that looks, nor is an eating apple an apple
> >     that eats, and laughing gas does not laugh. Peanut oil and olive oil are oils
> >     made from something, but what about baby oil? **And is this a contradiction:  "horse meat is dog meat"? Not at all, since the first is meat *from* horses and the other is meat *for* dogs.**

This is an excerpt from the linguistic book named "An introduction to Linguistics" written by "Fromkin V. Rodman R., Hyams N.". I am wondering if "dog meat" really means "meat for dog" or "dog food" in idiomatic English. It seems to me that "dog meat" only means "meat from dogs".

Comment: Should "contraction" have been "contradiction"?

Comment: In the West we don't eat dogs, so we don't have a common phrase for meat made from dogs. But I agree with you that we don't usually use the phrase "dog meat" when we mean "dog food".

Comment: When was it written? [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog+meat%2Cdog+food&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdog%20meat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdog%20food%3B%2Cc0) shows that "dog food" didn't start becoming more common than "dog meat" until the 1930's.

Comment: Baby oil, North Sea oil, engine oil and castor oil all have different meanings.

Comment: I think I've heard comedians using the different types of "oils" in jokes.

Comment: Before 1900 I think dogs had to forage for themselves in the farmyard, catching rats and so forth. The idea of giving 'food' to a dog is modern.

Comment: @Barmar - "Dog meat" is a fairly common (though a hair archaic) epithet for a worthless person, and one who, in other times, might have been fed to the dogs.  (Any more, people try not to think of where dog food might come from.)

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I've heard that idiom. But the quote in the question seems to be talking about literal dog meat, not metaphorical. And I wasn't actually sure whether the metaphor comes from food for vs. from dogs, nor how old the idiom is.

Comment: @Barmar - You can easily find mentions (in the Ngram you linked) of beef being used for "dog meat" going back to 1900.

Comment: @Barmar I would suggest that the term "dog meat" (meaning dog food) is still, within context, an everyday term. If you ask a butcher what he does with certain unwanted parts of a carcass, he is perfectly likely to say "it goes for dog meat".

Comment: @HotLicks That's what I said -- it wasn't until the 1930's that "dog food" took over.

Comment: There are a lot of ways in which nouns can be compounded, and _horse meat_ and _dog meat_ illustrate two of them. A couple more examples: _pony ride_ means that someone gets a ride **on** a pony, but _snake bite_ means that someone gets a bite **by** a snake.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. I should have typed "contradiction" instead of "contraction".

Comment: @JohnLawler While *sound bite* means a bite **of** sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OED, *dog meat* has two meanings, either

1. ‘Meat prepared for dogs; esp. offal, horseflesh, etc., cut into pieces’ (first recorded use 1505) or
2. ‘Dog’s flesh used as food’ (first recorded use 1805).

However, my intuition is that the **latter meaning is more common**, and a quick internet search and look in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) seems to indicate that, as well.

One likely factor in this is the context of use: While meaning (2) **frequently shows up** in writings about countries where dog meat is part of the regular local diet, the occasions where one would use meaning (1) are **comparatively few**.

Another likely factor is that the semantic pattern *X meat* meaning ‘meat of X’ is **available for all animals**, while the pattern *X meat* ‘meat for X’ is much **more restricted** (e.g. not usually applicable to herbivores).

Yet another factor might be how semantically essential the argument is. While every slab of meat necessarily has an **origin** or source, there may not be an intended **recipient** or purpose, or it may change.

However, regardless of whether meaning (2) is usually more common, meaning (1) will become the preferred reading in contexts where meaning (2) would lead to a contradiction – such as the sentence you quoted from the book.